# Spark SQL Group By Consecutive Sequence of Integers

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I have a table which I want to create events from it. My user is watching a video which is defined as a list of sub_parts, with bytes downloaded for every sub_part asked from.

For example Alice is watching a video with 15 parts of 5 seconds, she watched the first three parts then she skipped to the part 7 and played two more parts, but in the end she never finished the video.

So I want to recreate this trace of events for every user with Spark SQL (and most likely UDF but help me with this, I don't understand how can I make it work)

```
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
|   |   Name     | Video_part  | Bytes Dl    |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 | Alice      |       1     |      200    |
| 2 | Alice      |       2     |      250    |
| 3 | Alice      |       3     |      400    |
| 1 | Alice      |       7     |      100    |
| 2 | Alice      |       8     |      200    |
| 3 | Bob        |       1     |     1000    |
| 1 | Bob        |       32    |      500    |
| 2 | Bob        |       33    |      400    |
| 3 | Bob        |       34    |      330    |
| 1 | Bob        |       15    |      800    |
| 2 | Bob        |       16    |      400    |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

So what I want is to group by consecutive integers in video_part which are my events **play**, and when there is a break in this consecutive list, this is either an event **skin_in** or **skip_out**, for each portion of **play** I wanna get the mean of the bytes downloaded too :

```
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   |   Name     | Number_play |    Event    | Number_skips| Mean_BytesDL|
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 | Alice      |       3     |     Play    |       0     |      283,3  |
| 2 | Alice      |       0     |    Skip_in  |       4     |      0      |
| 3 | Alice      |       2     |     Play    |       0     |      150    |
| 1 | Bob        |       1     |     Play    |       0     |      1000   |
| 2 | Bob        |       0     |    Skip_in  |       31    |      0      |
| 3 | Bob        |       3     |     Play    |       0     |      410    |
| 2 | Bob        |       0     |    Skip_out |       19    |      0      |
| 3 | Bob        |       2     |     Play    |       0     |      600    |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Problem is I can do it in Python or in Scala using respectively sub_pandas df with loops or sublists with map and foreach, but it is taking too long to run it on 1 To of datas. Even if I run it on my cluster of nodes.

So I'm wondering is there a way to do it in Spark SQL, I have researched a little over UDF with Groupby, flatMap or Agg. But I'm having trouble as this is completely new for me, hope you can help me somehow !

I was thinking with something like :

- SortBy Name
- Through every unique name :
- Aggregate the video_part with UDF -> which creates three new columns
  with one which the avg of the bytesDL on the portion

I know this is pretty specific but maybe someone can help me,

Thanks in advance and have a good day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `UDF` function would give you row by row calculation functionality with columns you pass to `UDF` function, and it would be difficult to fulfill your criteria with that.
I suggest you to use `Window` function, in which you can define grouping , ordering and even framing types.

```
PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ... frame_type BETWEEN start AND end
```

[databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) and [Mastering Apache Spark 2](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-windows.html) should be sufficient enough to start with. 
 
What I can suggest more is for the first phase of calculating Mean_BytesDL , in which you can

```
Window.partitionBy(col("name")).orderBy(col("Video_part").asc).rowsBetween(<choose rows so that each frame would contian all the consecutive Video_part played>)
```

you can proceed the same for other columns and drop all unnecessary rows.

Working on a custom `frame_type` in not impossible but is certainly a nightmare.

Meanwhile I got you the solution by using `UDAF` but before that please make sure there is another `column` which identifies the latest download for a user

```
+---+-----+----------+--------+------+
|sn |Name |Video_part|Bytes D1|latest|
+---+-----+----------+--------+------+
|1  |Alice|1         |200     |      |
|2  |Alice|2         |250     |      |
|3  |Alice|3         |400     |      |
|1  |Alice|7         |100     |      |
|2  |Alice|8         |200     |latest|
|3  |Bob  |1         |1000    |      |
|1  |Bob  |32        |500     |      |
|2  |Bob  |33        |400     |      |
|3  |Bob  |34        |330     |      |
|1  |Bob  |15        |800     |      |
|2  |Bob  |16        |400     |latest|
+---+-----+----------+--------+------+
```

After that create `UDAF` as below

```
private class MovieAggregateFunction(inputSourceSchema : StructType) extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  var previousPlay : Int = _
  var previousEvent : String = _
  var playCount : Int = _
  var skipCount : Int = _
  var sum : Double = _
  var finalString : String = _
  var first : Boolean = _

  def inputSchema: StructType = inputSourceSchema

  def bufferSchema: StructType = new StructType().add("finalOutput", StringType)

  def dataType: DataType = StringType

  def deterministic: Boolean = false

  def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    previousPlay = 0
    previousEvent = "Play"
    playCount = 0
    skipCount = 0
    sum = 0.0
    finalString = ""
    first = true
    buffer.update(0,"")
  }

  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    val sn = input.getInt(0)
    val name = input.getString(1)
    val vPart = input.getInt(2)
    val eventType = getEventType(previousPlay, vPart)
    val dPart = input.getInt(3).toDouble
    val latest = input.getString(4)
    if(previousEvent.equalsIgnoreCase(eventType) && eventType.equalsIgnoreCase("Play")){
      playCount +=1
      sum += dPart
    }
    if(!previousEvent.equalsIgnoreCase(eventType)){
      if(first) {
        finalString = name + "::" + playCount + "::" + previousEvent + "::" + "0" + "::" + sum / playCount + "&&" +
          name + "::" + "0" + "::" + eventType + "::" + skipCount + "::" + "0"
      }
      else{
        finalString = finalString+"&&"+name + "::" + playCount + "::" + previousEvent + "::" + "0" + "::" + sum / playCount +
          "&&" + name + "::" + "0" + "::" + eventType + "::" + skipCount + "::" + "0"
      }
      playCount = 1
      sum = 0
      sum += dPart
      previousEvent = "Play"
      first = false
    }
    if(latest.equalsIgnoreCase("latest")){
      finalString = finalString+"&&"++name+"::"+playCount+"::"+previousEvent+"::"+skipCount+"::"+sum/playCount
    }
    previousPlay = vPart
    buffer.update(0, finalString)
  }

  def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
    buffer1.update(0, buffer1.getString(0) + buffer2.getString(0))
  }

  def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    buffer.getString(0)
  }

  def getEventType(firstPlay: Int, secondPlay: Int): String ={
    if(firstPlay < secondPlay && secondPlay - firstPlay == 1){
      skipCount = 0
      "Play"
    }
    else if(firstPlay < secondPlay && secondPlay-firstPlay > 1){
      skipCount = secondPlay - firstPlay
      "Skip_in"
    }
    else if(firstPlay > secondPlay){
      skipCount = firstPlay - secondPlay
      "Skip_out"
    }
    else
      ""
  }
}
```

Then call the `UDAF` by passing `inputSchema` and apply `aggregation` function

```
val udaf = new MovieAggregateFunction(df.schema)
df = df.groupBy("Name").agg(udaf(col("sn"), col("Name"), col("Video_part"), col("Bytes D1"), col("latest")).as("aggOut"))
```

The output until now is

```
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Name |aggOut                                                                                                                  |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Bob  |Bob::1::Play::0::1000.0&&Bob::0::Skip_in::31::0&&Bob::3::Play::0::410.0&&Bob::0::Skip_out::19::0&&Bob::2::Play::0::600.0|
|Alice|Alice::3::Play::0::283.3333333333333&&Alice::0::Skip_in::4::0&&Alice::2::Play::0::150.0                                 |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

We already have the desired output. Now to convert the `aggOut` column into a separate `dataFrame`, convert it to `rdd`, `split` them and convert back to `dataFrame` as below

```
val lineRdd = df.rdd.flatMap(row => row(1).toString.split("&&").toList)
val valueRdd = lineRdd.map(line => {
  val list = mutable.MutableList[String]()
  for(value <- line.split("::")){
    list += value
  }
  Row.fromSeq(list)
  })
val outputFields = Vector("Name", "Number_play", "Event", "Number_skips", "Mean_bytesDL")
val schema = StructType(outputFields.map(field => StructField(field, DataTypes.StringType, true)))
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(valueRdd, schema)
df.show(false)
```

The final output is

```
+-----+-----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
|Name |Number_play|Event   |Number_skips|Mean_bytesDL     |
+-----+-----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
|Bob  |1          |Play    |0           |1000.0           |
|Bob  |0          |Skip_in |31          |0                |
|Bob  |3          |Play    |0           |410.0            |
|Bob  |0          |Skip_out|19          |0                |
|Bob  |2          |Play    |0           |600.0            |
|Alice|3          |Play    |0           |283.3333333333333|
|Alice|0          |Skip_in |4           |0                |
|Alice|2          |Play    |0           |150.0            |
+-----+-----------+--------+------------+-----------------+
```

Note : the final `dataTypes` are all `String`, you can change them according to your need.

Answer (score 3):

I have a much simpler approach. I'll first explain in words. When you have consecutive integers in ordered rows, the following thing happens: the difference between the row_number and the value in the row, for every row, remains constant.
So, in a window function over Name ordered by Video_part add an additional column, say "diff", in which you put Video_part - row_number(). This will make all rows with consecutive values to have the same value in this column.
You can then just groupBy("Name", "diff") and you have the groups you wanted.
Right? So a simple example, imagine the ordered list of numbers in column "value" with their corresponding (value - row index) added column, "diff":

```
+----+------+-----+
|row |value |diff |
+----+------+-----+
|0   |2     |2    |
|1   |3     |2    |
|2   |4     |2    |
|3   |7     |4    |
|4   |8     |4    |
|5   |23    |18   |
|6   |24    |18   |
+----+------+-----+
```

So, grouping by diff would get you groups of rows with consecutive values

Applying this will require something that can provide the row number in an ordered list of rows. Windows can do that. Now to the code:

```
val win = Window.partitionBy("Name").orderBy("Video_part")
df.withColumn("diff", $"Video_part" - row_number().over(win))
```

Then just group by "diff" and "Name" and aggregate however you want

Answer (score 0):

if you do it as you say you can do (Python, with loops, map and foreach), no wonder it takes too long.  I would do this using numpy and use its array logic.  I'm going to solve a simplified version of your question, then see it yourself if it helps you, I'm sure it will help me, since I'm having precisely this simplified version of your problem.

so, I have a list of integers, in my case it is sorted, and I want to convert it into a sequence of non contiguous ranges.

what I do is to build two lists, one where I strip the first element, one where I strip the last, and subtract one from the other.  for ease of reading, I also subtract the expected `1`, for subsequent values, so I can compare against `0`.  this index I zip together with the stripped indices lists (using dstack for efficiency), then the rest is quite obvious I think.

```py
# orig is your original array of integers, in my case, it's sorted.
import numpy as np
i = np.array(orig)
index = i[1:] - i[:-1] - 1
zipped = np.dstack((index, i[:-1], i[1:]))[0]
np_todo = zipped[index!=0,:]  # selecting using a boolean array
todo = list(np_todo)  # needed to use .pop()
todo.reverse()  # not necessary, you can work from the top if you prefer
ranges = []     # the result we will build
singletons = [] # not worth being called a range
bottom = i[0]   # bottom of first range
while todo:
    _, top, next_bottom = todo.pop()
    if top != bottom:
        ranges.append((bottom, top))
    else:
        singletons.append(top)
    bottom = next_bottom
print(singletons)
print(ranges)
```

in my own case, I will discard all ranges that aren't at least 3 long, and I'm very interested in hearing about whether this is fast enough for your needs.